# Issue in IE when using Fabric.js

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, fabricjs

I used **http://fabricjs.com/** library am having this problem I need to fix In Internet Explorer the text I add take place beside the selected area but in Chrome and Firefox wit work probably.

[IE snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU2Nk.png).

[Chrome snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXIC4.png).

```
var text_bottom = new fabric.Text(text_bottom, {
            originX: 'center',
            left:270,
            top: 490,
            fontFamily:'AsmaaFont',
            fill:"#C0C0C0",
            fontSize: 50,
            textAlign: 'center'
        });
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove:

```
 textAlign: 'center'
```

So your code will be:

```
var text_bottom = new fabric.Text(text_bottom, {
            originX: 'center',
            left:270,
            top: 490,
            fontFamily:'AsmaaFont',
            fill:"#C0C0C0",
            fontSize: 50
        });
```